# Register and Near smart contracts

Tags: github, blockchain, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

In `NEAR`, there are two smart contracts created in genesis: `near` and `register` smart contracts. These contracts handle account IDs, but I can't seem to locate their source code. Could someone please point me to the relevant code on GitHub?

https://explorer.near.org/accounts/near

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`registrar` account does not have any contract deployed to it, it is still controlled by a full access key controlled by NEAR Foundation: https://explorer.near.org/accounts/registrar

`near` account uses [near-linkdrop](https://github.com/near/near-linkdrop) contract.

Comment: Ahh near-linkdrop. seems just right.
But what are those "Batch Transaction" in https://explorer.near.org/accounts/registrar. creating top-level named accounts

Comment: Every transaction can have a list of native actions (there are 9 native actions: transfer NEAR, stake NEAR (only used by validators), create named account, delete account, add access key, delete access key, call function, deploy code, delegate actions (meta-transactions)). Batched actions are either all applied or all rejected (if any action of the batch fails)

Answer (score 2):

registrar is the only top-level account that can create other top-level  account while other accounts (including top-level) can only create their sub-accounts.